# Does Yii Framework Has Some kind of Caching pre-enabled inside?

Tags: php, yii

I am new to the Yii framework and i Changed a Folder name inside of my project and it took about 15 minutes for Yii or web server to understand it and not showing error about the file path .

I checked out my Apache Web server configuration (it is local) , it does not contain any caching on it and i did not install any caching software on it so i was just thinking maybe there is some kind of caching mechanism turned on in this framework by default, is it ?

Comment: There is not. But maybe you face the same problem as this guy: http://askubuntu.com/questions/267405/how-to-prevent-caching-of-php-files/267430

Comment: no sir .that is not it.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yii has various caching components built in.

The link below gives an overview....

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview

Comment: I don't want to use one sir , i just want to know if there is one pre enabled.

Comment: It's not enable by default. But still it depends on your application config.

Comment: I do not config anything in it.